# Terminal command to create a .tar.gz files from 1,000,000 .json files (without including any directory)

Tags: bash, macos, gzip, tar

I have a directory with plus 1,000,000 `.json` files and used the following command to build a `j.tar.gz` only from json files (without including the `/Library/WebServer/a/a/e/j/` path):

`cd /Library/WebServer/a/a/e/j && tar -zcvf j.tar.gz *.json`

This error happened: `...Argument list too long`. Would you suggest a better command to accomplish this task? Thanks.

Comment: There are things other than JSON files in this directory? (If not, why specify `*.json` at all?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An initial caveat: `tar` is not a standards-defined tool (the POSIX archiver is `pax`), so its behavior can vary between platforms without any minimal guaranteed baseline. Your mileage may vary.

---

Since this is flagged for `bash`, you can use `<()` -- a process substitution -- to generate a filename which, when read, will emit a subprocess's output without the need for a temporary file. (This will typically be implemented as either a `/dev/fd` name if your operating system supports them, or a named pipe otherwise).

If you only want the `cd` to apply to the `tar` command, you can do that as follows, putting it in a subshell and using `exec` to have the subshell replace itself with the `tar` command, avoiding the fork penalty that a subshell otherwise creates:

```
dir=/Library/WebServer/a/a/e/j
(cd "$dir" && exec tar --null -zcvf j.tar.gz -T <(printf '%s\0' *.json) )
```

Alternately, if your `tar` supports it, you can use `--include` to tell `tar` itself to filter the names:

```
tar -C "$dir" --include='*.json' -cvzf "$dir/j.tar.gz" .
```

---

Points of note:

- `printf '%s\n' *.json` is immune from this because `printf` is a shell builtin; thus, the glob results aren't put in an `execv`-family syscall's arguments, so `ARG_MAX` doesn't apply.
- Using `--null` on `find` and `'%s\0'` on `printf` (or `-print0` if you were generating your list of names with `find`) prevents a maliciously-generated name with a literal newline from being able to inject arbitrary names into your stream. Think about what happens if someone runs `mkdir -p $'hello/\n/etc/passwd\n.json'` -- you don't want `/etc/passwd` going into your tarball.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer,Cheers.

Comment: there is a `j` directory inside the `j.tar.gz` file. How can I change the `j` directory permission inside the `j.tar.gz` to `755`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find . -type f -name "*.json" > ./include_file && tar -zcvf j.tar.gz --files-from ./include_file
```

NOTE:  This was tested successfully on CentOS/RedHat 6.7.

Comment: `.json`, not `.sh`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I was editing that at about the same time you caught it.  :-)  (Didn't have enough .json files to test it.)  But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit set by your system.  You can check

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

mine returns

```
131072
```

Alternatively, you can create a file list for `tar` and use `-T`, `--files-from F` option to get names instead of globbing which hits the max args limit.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the nature of the limit (ie. that it's bytes, rather than number of arguments, and that environment variables as opposed to only command-line length counts against it).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
> cd /Library/WebServer/a/a/e/j
> find . -name '*.json' -maxdepth 1 | xargs tar -czvf j.tar.gz --add-file
```

It does not require temporary file and does not need to do `*.json` in the shell which would fail.

Checked on Ubuntu haven't got Mac at hand.

Comment: If you have more files than will fit in `ARG_MAX`, this will run `tar` more than once and overwrite the old `j.tar.gz` on every subsequent invocation. It *is* possible to tell tar to append to an existing archive, but that's not `-c`.